# Change only one color channel in fragment shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

I would like to know how to change only one color channel and keep the 2 others color channels to their initial values.

```
#version 410
layout(location = 0) out vec3 color_out;
precision highp float;


void main()
{
        float z = 0.3f;
        color_out = vec3(z, my actual value , my actual value)
}
```

How can I retrieve the actual value or change only one channel (the red one)?

I tried this code for drawing

```
glColorMask(true,true ,true, true);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, totalconnectedtriangles_);
glColorMask(true,false,false,false);
```

This solution works but create really strange artifacts when I move the window. Does the fragment shader take place right after glDrawArrays (after my second color mask) or during glDrawArrays ?

Comment: Usually you pass the color through the vertex shader,so you can use the initial color

Comment: So I'm forced to use a vertext shader right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[glColorMask](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glColorMask.xml) allows you to select per channel what is updated for your fragment. So you can decide to update only R by doing
`glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE);`

Comment: mmmh this solution is good, but the problem is that i want to set the G and B during the drawing stage, and untouch them in the fragment shader, unefortunately after adding this line on my code, glColorPointer has no more effect :(

Comment: you seem to be confusing a number of things... "the drawing stage" and "the fragment shader" are part of the same thing. Triangles go through the pipeline, and when they get transformed into single points (fragments) a small program runs on them to decide their color. The fragment shader. So it's completely part of the draw, it's the only thing that decides the color of the fragment (from its inputs)

Comment: Thank you for highlighting this point. Is there any solution to use glColorPointer to set RGB channels and olny change the red channel in my fragment shader ? maybe now I read your comment my question is more clear

Comment: Yes, if you are passing colors to the fragment shader through glColorPointer and the default vertex color pipeline (no shader), you'll have the input color available in the fragment shader as the system variable `gl_Color` (in glsl 1.4). Note however that using the fixed function pipeline (i.e. no vertex shader, and glColorPointer) has been deprecated for more than 5 years now and is therefore not available in more recent versions of the glsl language. You really should look at implementing this with your own vertex shader.

Comment: If i understood well a good startegy is to get vertex color from  vertex shader and input it to fragment shader, to use it for the 2 colors channels I want to stay unchanged